# Wait for multiple elements to be removed React testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a react application where I'm using jest and react testing library for my unit tests. I have a unit test where I want to test that `SomeComponent when loaded doesn't render any skeleton`.
SomeComponent renders skeletons when data isn't loaded yet. Problem is that multiple skeletons are rendered and `waitForElementToBeRemoved` only takes one HTMLElement.

So I was wondering if there was a way to `waitForMultipleElementsToBeRemoved`?

```
test("SomeComponent when loaded doesn't render any skeleton", async () => {
    render(
      <SomeComponent />,
    )

  const skeletons = screen.getAllByTestId("skeleton");
  await waitForElementToBeRemoved(skeletons);

  expect(
    screen.queryByTestId("skeleton") 
  ).not.toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Note:

This test works as intended when there is only one skeleton.

Answer (score 4):

You can just:

```
await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.getAllByTestId("initLoader"));
```

or in your case:

```
await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => skeletons);
```

I think you just missing the callback. Otherwise your code is fine!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this if you only want to test for 1 skeleton to be rendered

```js
test("only 1 skeleton", async () => {
  const { getAllByTestId } = render(
    <div data-testId="skeleton">spooky skeleton</div>
  );

  const skeletons = getAllByTestId("skeleton");
  
  await waitFor(()=>{
    expect(skeletons.length).toBe(1);
  })
});
```

Here, I use `getAllByTestId`, but instead of checking for it to not be in the document, I just check if the length of the returned query is 1, meaning there is only one `skeleton` element being rendered.

I also wrap it in a `waitFor` as I'm assuming that the skeletons disappear over time. Note that the default timeout is only 1000ms, but this can be configured using the `options` [parameter](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor).

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-demo-forked-unyhf?file=/src/__tests__/hello.js)

Comment: Thanks for your input. Initially when SomeComponent is rendered it renders skeletons. Those skeletons will disappear when data is fetched. I'm currently testing that the skeletons disappear after data is fetched.

Comment: @Deeple so I suppose the test flow could be something like this? render component -> check if there are skeletons (expect some) -> call api -> wait for there to be no skeletons?

Comment: Yeah sounds right. Api will be called immediately when component is rendered.